# Haskell: Type mismatch in function using foldr

Tags: haskell

I don't understand why there is an error in these functions:

```
countEqualPairs:: Eq a => [a] -> Int
countEqualPairs (s:ss) = foldr test s ss

test :: Eq a => a -> a -> Int
test s c = if (c == s) then 1 else 0
```

Error Message:

> ```
> Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
> from the context (Eq a)
>   bound by the type signature for
>             countEqualPairs :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
>   at Blatt06.hs:30:20-37
>  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
>      the type signature for countEqualPairs :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
>      at Blatt06.hs:30:20
> Relevant bindings include
>  ss :: [a] (bound at Blatt06.hs:31:20)
>   s :: a (bound at Blatt06.hs:31:18)
>  countEqualPairs :: [a] -> Int (bound at Blatt06.hs:31:1)
>  In the second argument of `foldr', namely `s'
>  In the expression: foldr test s ss
> ```

Anybody there who can explain, what I got wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: a side from the `flip` @MrTsjolder mentioned I don't think the function will do what you want (there are more errors in there) - what is this function supposed to do?

Comment: Even if that were typeable, your ultimate result would be either 0 or 1, which is probably not what you're aiming for.

Comment: this is homework right (which is no problem - no sorrow) - but it would help if you could explain what the function is supposed to do (you can post the exercise - we see what you've tried) - but as you are new - please edit your question (most add things as comments or as an answer instead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` as can be found on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=foldr) expects a function of the form `a -> b -> b`, but your `test` function rather looks like `a -> a -> b`.

As [Carsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76051/carsten) mentioned, the `b` of your function doesn't even match the `b` from the accumulator and the info can be retrieved from GHCi when using `:t foldr` (this can be done for any function). Alternatives for what you are trying to do might be (if I got it right you try to count the number of doubles):

```
countEqualPairs [] = 0
countEqualPairs (s:ss) = if (s `elem` ss) then 1 + x else x
                         where x = countEqualPairs ss
```

Comment: no need for `hoogle` - just type `:t foldr` in ghci ;) - and `test` here will not fit in at all (the `b` is quite different from the `b` in the used `foldr`)

Comment: You're completely right, I got lost in my answer a bit (as can be seen in the edit-history), but thanks for making that clear

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the helpful comments and the answer. I solved it this way:

```
countEqualPairs :: Eq a => [a] -> Int countEqualPairs ss = sum (zipWith test (init ss) (tail ss)) test :: Eq a => a -> a -> Int test c1 c2 = if (c1 == c2) then 1 else 0
```